Como compartilhar uma img no instagram usando o navigator.share?
Eu tenho esse código que pega um trecho do meu html e transforma uma img e depois abre aquele modal do navegador que ira compartilha a img.
Porem em aparelhos Android tem a opção do store do insta, mas no IOS não tem essa opção. Como faço para aparecer o ícone de compartilhamento direto do store do insta?
html2canvas(itemPage, {
            scale: 3, // Escala de renderização
            logging: true, // Ativa o registro para debug, opcional
            backgroundColor: true, // Define o fundo como transparente, opcional
            imageTimeout: 0, // Remove o tempo limite para imagens serem carregadas, opcional
            width: itemPage.offsetWidth, // Define a largura do canvas para a largura do elemento
            height: itemPage.offsetHeight // Define a altura do canvas para a altura do elemento
        }).then(function (canvas) {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0); // Aqui você pode ajustar a qualidade da imagem, 1.0 é a qualidade máxima
            var blob = dataURItoBlob(imgData);
            var filesArray = [new File([blob], "screenshot.png", { type: "image/png" })];
            if (navigator.share) {
                navigator.share({
                    files: filesArray,
                    title: "De hoje ta pago!"
                })
                    .then(() => console.log('Compartilhado com sucesso'))
                    .catch((error) => consol.log('O Usuário não compartilhou!', error));
            } else {
                console.log('Navegador bloquando o compartilhamento')
            }
        });

Tem alguma propriedade ou configuração que devo fazer no navigator antes de usar o share?

Considerando que esta pergunta já foi feita e lá já foram dadas instruções, os comentários foram desativados nesta duplicata para evitar descentralizar informação.
